# Finding averages from a Multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this (along with the assigned value):

```
loop thru students {
     $count = 0;
     loop thru classes { 
          $myArr[$obj->student][$count] = $grade;
     }
}
```

I have data in a table:  Along the **top** header are classes.  Along the `sides` are students.  The cells each cross reference to are student grades.   I want the **bottom** row to be the average grades of all students in a class.

I have the info I need in the above array (The first part is the student id, the second part is the count of how many classes:  which will always be the same.

**The part I am struggling with is extracting the info I need to get averages:**

I essentially need to loop thru the SECOND part first to get the grade total and average by the count of students. I am not sure I am doing this the best way with the order of the array.  But this is the important info: *The outer loop is students, the inner loop is classes:  So that is why I have chosen the order I used.*

Can someone help me get on the right track?  It seemed so trivial to start.

**Edit -- added data as asked:**

Sample data;  student ID and grade; (some grades are blank but please ignore and assume they will be filled; I will handle those)

```
  [18273372] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40%
            [1] => 50%
            [2] => 100%
            [3] => 20%
            [4] => ---
            [5] => ---
            [6] => ---
            [7] => ---
            [8] => ---
            [9] => ---
            [10] => ---
            [11] => ---
            [12] => 50%
            [13] => ---
            [14] => ---
            [15] => ---
        )



 [18273372] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50%
            [1] => 50%
            [2] => 100%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => ---
            [5] => ---
            [6] => ---
            [7] => 55%
            [8] => ---
            [9] => 70%
            [10] => ---
            [11] => ---
            [12] => 50%
            [13] => ---
            [14] => ---
            [15] => ---
        )
```

I need the averages;  for example, position (or class) 0 is average 45%.  Again, 0 - 15 represent 16 different classes.  Class 0 for each student is the same.

EDIT:

Here is my updater code:

```
$avg[$obj->s_i_student_num][$count] = $gradebook->unitPercentage[$count];
                $totals = array();
                foreach($avg as $student_id => $scores) {
                      foreach($scores as $id => $percent) {

                            if ($percent == "---") { continue; } 

                            $percent = (int) $percent;
                            $totals[$id][] = $percent;

                      }
                }
```

Comment: Could you maybe output a print_r of the data or a sample array. I don't think anyone wants to hand type out a sample to test.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn  I have added the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method: Loop through your results and save each percentage by key into a temporary array, grouping them all together:

```
$totals = array();

foreach($test_data as $student_id => $scores) {
  foreach($scores as $id => $percent) {
    // Trim off the percent sign  
    $percent = (int) $percent;
    // Initialize array key if it's the first time
    if(!array_key_exists($id, $totals))
      $totals[$id] = array();
    $totals[$id][] = $percent;
  }
}
```

Then, run a pass over that array to average all the results by key, and add your percent sign back on:

```
// Affect original: pass variable by reference (&)
array_walk($totals, function(&$value) {
  // Sum values, divide by the size of the array (average) then add % on
  $value = array_sum($value) / count($value) . '%';
});
```

`print_r($totals)` shows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 45%
    [1] => 50%
    [2] => 100%
    [3] => 35%
    [12] => 50%
    [7] => 55%
    [9] => 70%
)
```

The keys there are the key of the original score in each array. [**Demo.**](https://eval.in/185041)

Comment: Actually, the casting as an integer line isn't necessary as it will happen when you run the sums anyway. Might be good to keep it there for reference though.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I would have gotten this conclusion any time soon.  I do get this error in my php log, `[] operator not supported for strings `;  that points to this line:  `$totals[$id][] = $percent;` (added code above)

Comment: I've updated the answer. You need to initialize the array key before you use it - my fault, being lazy :)